# PHP image swap based on day and url

Tags: php, background-image

My goal is to have a background image swapped out according to the day of the week and to the link the user came from.

example:

Monday, index.php = bg1.jpg

Monday, about.php = bg2.jpg

Tuesday, index.php = bg3.jpg

Tuesday, about.php = bg4.jpg

This is my switch that handles the case of the week but not sure how to go from here:

```
<?php

// Variables
$url = "images/days/";
$monImage = "$url"."bg_mon_a.jpg";
$tueImage = "$url"."bg_tue_a.jpg";
$wedImage = "$url"."bg_wed_a.jpg";
$thurImage = "$url"."bg_thu_a.jpg";
$friImage = "$url"."bg_fri_a.jpg";
$weekendImage = "$url"."bg_default.jpg";
$d = date("D");
//Function that switches between date images based on the actual day of the week in $d
switch ($d)
{
case Mon:
echo "<img id='bg_image' src=$monImage>\n";
break;
case Tue:
echo "<img id='bg_image' src=$tueImage>\n";
break;
case Wed:
echo "<img id='bg_image' src=$wedImage>\n";
break;
case Thu:
echo "<img id='bg_image' src=$thurImage>\n";
break;
case Fri:
echo "<img id='bg_image' src=$friImage>\n";
break;
default:
echo "<img id='bg_image' src=$weekendImage>\n";
}
//End
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the part you're having problems with? Adding an extra criteria to the switches, or getting the name of the referring link? And what will you do if there is no referring link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the link clicked to come to your site, you are looking for the `HTTP_REFERRER`, which is stored in the `$_SERVER` variables.

Try echoing out: `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'];` and you will see the website URL that sent the person to your site.

I think this is what you are asking, but if not, you will need to clarify a little more.

Now as far as images go:

```
$img='bg_'.strtolower(date("D")).'_a.jpg';
```

Just make sure that you change your weekend image names to `sat` and `sun`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've over complicated it.

```
$bgimage = 'bg_' . date ("D") . '.jpg';
echo '<img src="images/' . $bgimage . '">';
```

Then just make sure you have 7 files, one for each day:

```
bg_Mon.jpg
bg_Tue.jpg
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<img id='bg_image' src='images/days/bg_". strtolower(date("D")) ."'>\n";
```

Comment: Basically the same as what I posted ... but don't forget the '.jpg' in there.  :)

Answer (score 1):

if it's a background image you want, maybe you need something like

```
echo "<div id='div_with_background' style='background: url($weekendImage)'>\n";
echo 'some content';
echo '</div>';
```

also, if you want to test the link the user came from, do a switch on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but remember that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not guaranteed to have the real url the user came from.